# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture returns different CultureInfo for the same device for the same settings in Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

We are developing an application that requires the amount to be displayed. Now, this amount needs to be displayed in a formatted way with appropriate currency symbol like $,£ etc depending upon the region the application is being run.

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture seems to work fine for UWP and returns CulturalInfo depending upon the settings saved in the operating system/Windows machine.

But, I have observed that for android this code returns different CulturalInfo and results in an amount to be displayed with $ sometimes and £ the other.

It will be helpful if someone over the community can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to use `var androidLocale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;` to get the proper locale and translate that into a CultureInfo class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Cheesebaron already mentioned in the comments, you will have to use `Java.Util.Locale.Default`.

In order to convert this into an `CultureInfo` object, you will have to understand how `Java.Util.Locale` and `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` are formatted.

`Java.Util.Locale` uses the following format:

`<language code>[_<country code>[_<variant code>]]`

While `System.Globalization.CultureInfo` uses the following format:

`languagecode2>-country/regioncode2`

Therefor, the difference lies in the seperator they use: `-` versus `_`.

The following code snippet should give you an idea how to tackle this problem:

```
public System.Globalization.CultureInfo GetCurrentCultureInfo )
{
    var androidLocale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
    var netLanguage = androidLocale.ToString().Replace ("_", "-");

    return new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(netLanguage);
}
```